# How to close my modal with the key enter + onclick

Tags: javascript

I have a modal that takes an input and display it on the screen, it works fine when I press the button "Save". But I'd like it to work when I press the key enter. I've found a few answers but it doesn't really suit my code as I want both the onClick and press enter. 
I've also tried to change the button for a "submit" type but it doesn't work well.
Is there a quick and simple way to do that with my current code ?

```js
    function addMovie() {
    
      var i = document.getElementById('addedMovie');
      var d = document.createElement('div');
      d.id = "new-movie";
      d.innerHTML = "<p>" + "<img src='../images/movie.png'>" + i.value + "</p>";
      var p = document.getElementById('related-movies');
    
      p.appendChild(d);
    
    }
```

```html
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add a movie</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Movie title" name="movies[]" class="modal-input" id="addedMovie">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-login" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="addMovie();clearModal()">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Or is there a simpler a way to do that (by submiting the input in the modal and display it on the div of my choice for example ? because at the moment I am just taking the value inside the input but I don't think I am saving it into a variable)

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Where is element with id `related-movies` in your HTML?

Comment: you have 2 ways, one is to listen to onsubmit not just on change and your login button type is submit. second is to fire the same function is two different events, one onclick and one when user press enter key.

Comment: If you wrap your html code in <form> tag, then enter will work if any of your form input have focus. Then if you really need it you can use JS to keep focus on your input/button if there is no focus on any of the elements.

Comment: Hi, the "related-movie" is a div at the beggining of my html where I add the input. The last solution seems to work !

Answer (score 0):

Add a check for enter key press -

```
 <div id="modal" class="modal-content"> ...
   <input type="text" placeholder="Movie title" name="movies[]" class="modal-input" id="addedMovie" onkeypress="check(event)">
 </div>

function check(e) {
  if(e.key === "Enter") {
    addMovie();
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
  }
}
```

Comment: hi ! thanks a lot :) tje modal hide doesn't work though

Comment: did you add the modal id ?
<div id="modal" class="modal-content">

Comment: $('.modal').modal('hide'); works fine
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Jessicascn Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onkeypress event listener to the textbox and check for enter key pressed
Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cx7K4g9yP7YnGrxdWq02?p=preview)

```
 <input onkeyup="save(event)" type="text" placeholder="Movie title" name="movies[]" class="modal-input" id="addedMovie">
```

Javascript

```
function save(e){
 var key = 'which' in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;
 if (key == 13) {
   addMovie()
 }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to close the modal

Comment: Well I dont really have a modal.. I think the question was more related to how to use the onEnter... because we don't know what framework he is using for the modal.. $('#modal').modal('hide') is jquery... for foundation css its wolud be different and for vue.js also another thing

Comment: True, but says in title 'How to close my modal'

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works great ! I just need to add the clearModal in the function

Comment: Yes I don't know why it doesn't close the modal actually, I'm just using the bootstrap one

Comment: @Jessicascn what framework are you using for modal.. usually a clear modal.. clears the input elements of a modal...but doesn't close the modal as such.. and I guess you are now  adding a new question. if it is so, please open a new question in SO

Comment: I've found the solution (Surabhi answer below). Thanks :)